# Is libssh2_sftp_rename() a blocking api?

Tags: c++, sftp

I would like to know if libssh2_sftp_rename() is a blocking call or not. I received return code "LIBSSH2_ERROR_TIMEOUT" for the same api but the renaming of file is successful on the remote side. Is this expected or is there a way to know the call is successful or not.

Comment: did you set timeout with `libssh2_session_get_timeout`?

Comment: not with get_timeout, but i have set to 10 seconds. [ libssh2_session_set_timeout(session, 10000); ]